# Pumping lemma problem - Choosing the right string to pump

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, pumping-lemma

I have a problem finding the right string to pump for the following language:

$$L_1 = \{a^{p+q}b^rc^sd^{q+r}e^s \mid p, q, r, s \ge 0\}$$

Which string should I choose to pump? The problem is that I don't know how to handle the fact that I have $p+q$ and $q+r$?

Can I choose:
$$Z = a^{2n}b^nc^nd^{2n}e^s$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should prefer using latex instead of images. That makes it searchable and editable. You can click on edit of various questions to see examples.

Comment: I assume you refer to the **regular** pumping lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k$ is the *pump length* from the regular pumping lemma choose $w=c^ke^k$. Clearly, $w\in L_1$, but if you pump you have to change the number of $c$'s while leaving the $e$'s unaltered. Hence after pumping the word is no longer a member of $L_1$.

Comment: Hi ! Than you very much, the question was rather simple but I didn't noticed that p,q,r can be 0 :D